# REST API Error:: Querying ParentUniqueId for a list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, onedrive-for-business

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the parent Id for a list item so that I can query it as well.

For a given list item say id 101, I need to find the Id for its parent (the folder it lies under or the list if it's at the root, i.e, Document list Id)

Is this possible? I have been trying to get **ParentUniqueId** for a list item but its giving me the following error.

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
    "message": {
    "lang": "en-US",
    "value": "The field or property 'ParentUniqueId' does not exist."
    }
   }
  }
```

The call I am making is;

- https://{sitecollection}/{personal_site}/_api/Web/Lists(guid'blabla')/Items(blabla)?$select=ParentUniqueId

Is there any other way to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately [ListItem resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433(v=office.15).aspx#bk_ListItem) in SharePoint 2013 REST interface does **not** expose `ParentUniqueId` property.

But you could use the following query to return `ParentUniqueId` property for `ListItem`:

`/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items(<item id>)/FieldValuesAsText?$select=ParentUniqueId`

### References

[Lists and list items REST API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433(v=office.15).aspx)